# Настройка WiFi-роутера

Tags: свич, роутер

Имеется роутер TP-LINK TL-WR702N и свич COMPEX DSG1008, интернет l2tp. При попытке подключения роутер не видит сервер, хотя если кабель идет от свича напрямую к компьютеру, то все работает нормально.

Собственно лог:

```
 0147:L2TP request timeout ****. 0147:L2TP retry:2, nowTick:8876 0147:L2TP tx SCCRQ. 0146:L2TP retry:1, nowTick:8760     0145:L2TP tx SCCRQ. 0145:L2TP manually connecting.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: [@Frnk](http://admin.hashcode.ru/users/1286/frnk), если можно, пожалуйста поподробнее: 1. "при попытке подключения" - куда?2. "роутер не видит сервер" - какой сервер3. "то все работает нормально" - а как не работает?

Comment: Как адрес VPN сервера пишете? буквенный или цифровой?Попробуйте конектиться c PPTP.